# Get server relative url of a list in JS

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, list, javascript

I am really new in SharePoint dev, and sorry in advance if I am asking something weird or a completely wrong with this question.

The app is a SPA in angular (my world :)) which uses a sharepoint helper service to do some operation. In this example I am adding an item in a list (folder), everything works fine, the only thing is that in the method .set_folderUrl() I use an hardcoded path to the list. I would like to get the path url through another method (instead of the hardcoded path), if exists, from /sites of the list "*/sites/nameSite/Lists/ListName/"*"

Many thanks.

```
        // Get current web (comparable to SPWeb)
        var oWeb = hostContext.get_web();
        // Get list by title (comparable to SPList)
        var oList = oWeb.get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
        // Create new object for list item creation
        clientContext.load(oList);
        //Create List Item Infor and set the Folder Path for the item to be created.
        var listItemCreationInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();


        listItemCreationInfo.set_folderUrl("/sites/nameSite/Lists/ListName/" + rootFolder);
        var itemInfo = oList.addItem(listItemCreationInfo);

        angular.forEach(data, function (value, prop) {
                if (value != null) {
                    itemInfo.set_item(prop, value);
                }
        });


        // Update the new item
        itemInfo.update();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could get the list root folder relative url.

Include *'RootFolder'* when loading the list and get firstly the rootFolder and secondly the rootFolder relative url.

```
// Get current web (comparable to SPWeb)
var oWeb = hostContext.get_web();
// Get list by title (comparable to SPList)
var oList = oWeb.get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
// Create new object for list item creation
clientContext.load(oList, 'RootFolder');
//Create List Item Infor and set the Folder Path for the item to be created.
var listItemCreationInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();

var rootFolder = oList.get_rootFolder();
var url = rootFolder.get_serverRelativeUrl();

listItemCreationInfo.set_folderUrl(url);
var itemInfo = oList.addItem(listItemCreationInfo);

angular.forEach(data, function (value, prop) {
    if (value != null) {
        itemInfo.set_item(prop, value);
    }
});

// Update the new item
itemInfo.update();
```

(I have not tested the code)

Comment: `Include` is for collections, you'll only get List back. Use: `clientContext.load(oList, 'RootFolder');`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the server relative url of the list dynamically from the list object as given below:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var lists = context.get_web().get_lists();
context.load(lists,'Include(RootFolder)');
context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
var enumerator = lists.getEnumerator();
while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
   var list = enumerator.get_current();
   var rootFolder = list.get_rootFolder();

   var url = rootFolder.get_serverRelativeUrl();
   console.log(url);

}
},
function (sender, args) {
 console.log('error');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to load list `rootfolder` to get url of list:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("ListName"); // Name of the list
context.load(list);
context.load(list.get_rootFolder());

context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);

function onSuccess() {
  var rootFolder = list.get_rootFolder();
  var listURL = rootFolder.get_serverRelativeUrl(); // URL of the list
}

function onFail(sender, args) {
  console.log('Request Failed: ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```